# JMeter - CIFS support using JCIFS

Tags: jmeter, jcifs

Does anyone have attempted to write a script in JMeter using JCIFS to write/read/delete file on a remote share? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? You can turn any java code into a jmeter test case using a custom java sampler. See: http://ilkinbalkanay.blogspot.com/2010/03/load-test-whatever-you-want-with-apache.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensibility is the main feature of JMeter.

In regards to your question I would recommend the following:

1. Download [jcifs-*.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jcifs/jcifs) and drop it to the /lib folder of your JMeter installation
2. Download [groovy-all-*.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all) and put it to the same location
3. Restart Jmeter
4. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and put JCIFS-specific code there. See [JCIFS API documentation](https://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/) for classes and methods reference.
5. Make sure that "groovy" language is selected in the "Language" drop-down
6. Add more JSR223 Samplers if needed

Remember the following:

- don't refer JMeter Variables as `${VAR}` in groovy code
- if you use "Script" input rather than path to groovy file - put something unique (per sampler) into the "Compilation Cache Key" input

For detailed explanation of "why groovy", groovy scripting engine installation instructions and scripting best practices see [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide.